# Is it worth learning XNA now?

Tags: xna, c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the future of XNA in Windows 8 or how will manged games be developed in Windows 8?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22292/what-is-the-future-of-xna-in-windows-8-or-how-will-manged-games-be-developed-in)

It's no secret XNA's future is uncertain. Windows 8 only supports XNA desktop applications and not metro style apps. A number of 'rumors' are going around concerning Microsoft no longer supporting XNA after 4.0.

Despite this, do you believe it's worth picking up XNA now?

Comment: If you're concerned about that, consider using MonoGame. Windows 8 Store support is on the roadmap, if not already implemented. This has already been discussed at length, so voting to close.

Comment: This question isn't regarding how to develop games on Windows 8 or the state of XNA on Win8. This is regarding the state of XNA as a whole.

Comment: XNA as a whole? It's a really nice framework. Evaluating XNA as a whole is impossible, it all depends on what you're looking for.